# Animation from bottom for border-bottom

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have the following CSS which currently fades in the `border-bottom`.

```
.nav-bar-button {
  border-bottom: solid 13px transparent;
  min-width: 90px;
  padding: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  @media #{$for-tablet, $for-phone} {
    min-width: 81px;
  }

  &:hover {
    border-bottom: solid 13px $brand-primary;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition: .5s;
  }

  &.active {
    border-bottom: solid 7px $brand-primary;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    transition: .5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
}
```

What I want is to animate the `border-bottom` to appear as if it's sliding in from underneath of the `nav-bar-button`. Is there a way to do this while still avoiding the "jumping" from the navbar button expanding?

Here's the reactjs and HTML as well, edited to make it easier to understand:

```
  render () {
    let indicatorClasses = [styles.navBarButton]
    if (this.props.isActive) {
      indicatorClasses.push(styles.active)
    }

    return (
      <div
        className={indicatorClasses.join(' ')}
        onClick={(e) => { this.onClick(e) }} >
        <span className={styles.navBarButtonLabel}> {this.props.label.toUpperCase()} </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

<div class="style__navbar-buttons-container___1IIp4">
    <div class="ant-row">
        <div class="ant-col-8">
            <div class="style__nav-bar-button___30PmS">
            <span class="style__nav-bar-button-label___wjjHW">HOME</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you provide HTML so we can actually see whats going on?

Comment: Added the HTML and reactjs code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `border-bottom`, you can use an inset `box-shadow`. Also move your `transition` properties to the actual selector so that it could animate even when hover is removed.

Here is the updated SCSS.

```
.nav-bar-button {
  box-shadow: none;
  min-width: 90px;
  padding: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition: .5s;
  @media #{$for-tablet, $for-phone} {
    min-width: 81px;
  }

  &:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -13px 0 0 $brand-primary;
  }

  &.active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -7px 0 0 $brand-primary;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
  }
}
```